# Salesforce - unit testing for custom fields for Account object

Tags: salesforce

Suppose in `Account` object, it have 3 custom fields, there are `invoice_delivery_method`, `invoice_delivery_email` and `invoice_delivery_print`. For `invoice_delivery_method`, the type is picklist, and the possible values are `Email`, `Email and Print`, `Print` and `Other`. The rest of two custom fields are checkbox, and default to unchecked, which is `false`.

Now when user update the `invoice_delivery_method` field to `Email`, (either by Salesforce account page or by SOQL), the `invoice_delivery_email` is set to `true`, and `invoice_delivery_print` is set to `false`.

The way I did is create a trigger class like following:

```
trigger InvoiceDeliveryMethodTrigger on Account (before update) {
    InvoiceDeliveryMethodTriggerHandler.handleBeforeUpdate(Trigger.new);
}
```

Inside the handler class I did following:

```
public class InvoiceDeliveryMethodTriggerHandler {
    public static void handleBeforeUpdate(Account[] accounts){
        RecordType recordType = [select Id from RecordType where sobjecttype = 'Account' and Name =: MSSP_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults().Account_Record_Type__c];  
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if(account.RecordTypeId == recordType.Id) {
                System.debug('Information for Account: ' + account);
                System.debug('Information for Invoice Delivery Method: ' + account.Invoice_Delivery_Method__c);
                account.Invoice_Delivery_Email__c = false;
                account.Invoice_Delivery_Print__c = false;
                String delivery_method = account.Invoice_Delivery_Method__c;
                System.debug('String is not blank ' + String.isNotBlank(delivery_method));
                if (String.isNotBlank(delivery_method)){
                    if (delivery_method.equals('Email')){
                        account.Invoice_Delivery_Email__c = true;
                        account.Invoice_Delivery_Print__c = false;
                    }
                    else if (delivery_method.equals('Email and Mail')){
                        account.Invoice_Delivery_Email__c = true;
                        account.Invoice_Delivery_Print__c = true;
                    }
                    else if (delivery_method.equals('Mail')){
                        account.Invoice_Delivery_Email__c = false;
                        account.Invoice_Delivery_Print__c = true;                   
                    }  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also have one trigger class on `Account` after update, but I didn't change any value for that 3 custom field.

If I test via application, it seems that two custom field is got updated based on the value of `invoice_delivery_method`. But I got problems for my unit testing.

Here is the unit test class I wrote

```
    @isTest
    private class InvoiceDeliveryMethodTest {
        @isTest(SeeAllData=true)
        static void testAccountEmailSelected(){
            Account testAccount = new Account();
            // populating some of the mandatory field for Account
            testAccount.Invoice_Delivery_Method__c = 'Other';
            insert testAccount;        


            Account acct = [Select Id, Invoice_Delivery_Method__c, Invoice_Delivery_Email__c, Invoice_Delivery_Print__c from Account 
                            where Id =: testAccount.Id];
            acct.Invoice_Delivery_Method__c = 'Email';
            update acct;
            acct = [Select Id, Invoice_Delivery_Method__c, Invoice_Delivery_Email__c, Invoice_Delivery_Print__c from Account 
                    where Id =: testAccount.Id];    
            System.assertEquals('Email', acct.Invoice_Delivery_Method__c);
            System.assert(acct.Invoice_Delivery_Email__c);
            System.assert(!acct.Invoice_Delivery_Print__c);
            delete testAccount;

        }
}
```

When I run the test case, it fail on `System.assert(acct.Invoice_Delivery_Email__c);`

That fields still `false`. Why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think the simpler solution might be to use formulas instead of a trigger.

If you still want to go the trigger route I would suggest to not use seealldata.

That said the only thing I can really think of is the record type. When creating the account, can you assert that the record type Id is what you are expecting it to be?

Comment: Tried. I removed seealldata=true in the method header, and tried to insert the account, but it failing on my InvoiceDeliveryMethodTriggerHandler  due to the record type return empty result

Answer (score 0):

OK. I got it. Here is the way I did.

First remove all the `seealldata=true` in the `isTest` annotation.

Then according to http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-readcreate-record-types-in-apex.html, I create an `setup` method with `@testSetup` to create `Account` data and the `recordType`.

In the test method, I select the account that was created in `setup()`, change the value for  `invoice_delivery_method` and update the account. Then re-select again, and do the assert check. Once all the assert check passed, delete that account object, so it keep only 1 account object to use for next test method.

Comment: You don't have to delete the account after the test completes.  testSetup ensures that the same test data is used for all the tests within your test class.  If you only create one account in testSetup, then only one account will exist in any of your tests